# C# MethodInfo Invoke

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

I can't find the problem in this code. I'm trying to find a particular kind of property and invoke a method on it.

The function is the following:

```
private string GetLangTranslator(object root)
{
     var properties = root.GetType().GetProperties();

     foreach (var property in properties)
     {
         if (typeof(MultiLanguage) == property.PropertyType)
         {                    
                MethodInfo m = property.PropertyType.GetMethod("Translate");

                return m.Invoke(property.PropertyType, new object[] {Value1}) as string;                    
         }
     }

     return null;
}
```

And the exception is the following:

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should:

```
object propValue = property.GetValue(root);
return m.Invoke(propValue, new object[] {Value1}) as string;
```

The first parameter of `Invoke` is the instance of the object you want to call the method/property... So need to retrieve the value of the property first.